# gCentroid (rgeos) R vs. Actual Centroid (in python)

Tags: python, r, numpy, polygon, centroid

**Summary: I thought that using gCentroid in R would return the centroid of a group of points, however I realised that for some reason it actually returns the geometric mean and not the centroid**

I wanted to replicate a centroid calculation I did in R:

> gCentroid {rgeos}

The centre of mass of these points:

```
34.7573,    -86.678606  
38.30088,   -76.520266  
38.712147,  -77.158616  
39.704905,  -84.126463
```

... using the r-script ...

```
require(rgdal)
require(rgeos)

no_am_eq_co <- "+proj=eqdc +lat_0=0 +lon_0=0 +lat_1=20 +lat_2=60 +x_0=0 +y_0=0 +ellps=GRS80 +datum=NAD83 +units=m +no_defs"
wgs84 <- "+proj=longlat +datum=WGS84"

df <- as.data.frame(list(c(34.7573, 
                           38.30088, 
                           38.712147, 
                           39.704905),
                         c(-86.678606,
                           -76.520266,
                           -77.158616, 
                           -84.126463)))

df$Name <- "points_A"
colnames(df) <- c("lat", "lon", "Name")

# FROM: Coordinates are geographic latitude/longitudes
coordinates(df) <- c("lon", "lat")
proj4string(df) <- CRS(wgs84)

# TO: Project into North America Equidistant Conic
df <- spTransform(df, CRS(no_am_eq_co))

# Get centroids
ctrs <- lapply(unique(df$Name), 
               function(x) gCentroid(SpatialPoints(df[df$Name==x,])))
ctrsout <- setNames( ctrs , unique(df$Name ) )

# Create data frame 
df <- do.call(rbind, lapply(ctrsout, data.frame, stringsAsFactors=FALSE))
coordinates(df) <- c("x", "y")
proj4string(df) <- CRS(no_am_eq_co) 
df <- as.data.frame(spTransform(df, CRS(wgs84)))
names(df) <- c("longitude", "latitude")

print(df$latitude)
print(df$longitude)
```

Came to:

```
37.94873834, -81.18378815
```

I constructed the following example in python - I wanted to replicate the calculation, using:

[image]

[image]

[image]

```
import numpy as np
from pyproj import Proj, transform

# Using: http://www.spatialreference.org/ref/esri/102010/ we get the Proj4js format
na_eq_co = "+proj=eqdc +lat_0=0 +lon_0=0 +lat_1=20 +lat_2=60 +x_0=0 +y_0=0 +ellps=GRS80 +datum=NAD83 +units=m +no_defs"
wgs84 = "+proj=longlat +datum=WGS84"

def proj_arr(points,proj_from,proj_to):
    inproj = Proj(proj_from)
    outproj = Proj(proj_to)
    func = lambda x: transform(inproj,outproj,x[0],x[1])
    return np.array(list(map(func, points)))

def get_polygon_centroid(polygon):
    #https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Centroid#Centroid_of_polygon
    pol = np.array(polygon)
    if np.any(pol[-1] != pol[0]):
        pol = np.append(pol,[pol[0]], axis=0)
    pol_area = get_polygon_area(pol)
    x = pol[:,0]
    y = pol[:,1]
    Cx = np.sum((x[:-1] + x[1:]) * ((x[:-1] * y[1:]) - (y[:-1] * x[1:]))) / (6. * pol_area)
    Cy = np.sum((y[:-1] + y[1:]) * ((x[:-1] * y[1:]) - (y[:-1] * x[1:]))) / (6. * pol_area)
    return np.array([Cx, Cy])

def get_polygon_area(polygon):
    pol = np.array(polygon)
    x = pol[:,0]
    y = pol[:,1]
    return np.sum( (x[:-1] * y[1:]) - (y[:-1] * x[1:]) ) / 2 

def get_polygon_mean(polygon):
    pol = np.array(polygon)
    x = pol[:,0]
    y = pol[:,1]
    return np.array([np.mean(x),np.mean(y)])

def run_test(points):
    points = points[:,::-1] #Flip-axis (so that longitude x-axis, latitude y-axis)
    points_proj = proj_arr(points,wgs84,na_eq_co)

    centroid_proj = get_polygon_centroid(points_proj)
    mean_proj = get_polygon_mean(points_proj)

    centroid = proj_arr([centroid_proj],na_eq_co,wgs84)
    mean = proj_arr([mean_proj],na_eq_co,wgs84)
    return (centroid[:,::-1][0], mean[:,::-1][0])

if __name__ == '__main__':
    my_points = np.array([[34.7573,-86.678606],
                       [38.30088,-76.520266],
                       [38.712147,-77.158616],
                       [39.704905,-84.126463]])

    test = run_test(my_points)
    print("Centroid calculation: {0}\nMean calculation {1}".format(test[0],test[1]))
```

From this I get:

```
37.72876321 -82.35113685
```

Not:

```
37.94873834,-81.18378815
```

With a bit more digging I added a function give me the geometric mean:

```
Centroid calculation: [ 37.72876321 -82.35113685]
Mean calculation [ 37.94873834 -81.18378815]
```

I realised that for some reason the gCentroid seems to be calculating the geometric mean not the feature centroid (I have added a mean function, which you can see matches the R-result)

**Edit:**

I thought that perhaps the reason was: since I had a grouping of points, instead of fitting a random polygon through them - like me in the example - or even a convex hull and then taking the centroid of that, the command would default to a mean calculation if the data-type was 'point'. So I explicitly passed it a polygon:

```
x = readWKT(paste("POLYGON((-6424797.94257892  7164920.56353916,
                  -5582828.69570672  6739129.64644454,
                  -5583459.32266293  6808624.95123077,
                  -5855637.16642608  7316808.01148585,
                  -5941009.53089084  7067939.71641507,
                  -6424797.94257892  7164920.56353916))"))

python_cent = readWKT(paste("POINT(-5941009.53089084  7067939.71641507)"))
r_cent = gCentroid(x) 

plot(x)
plot(r_cent,add=T,col='red')
plot(python_cent, add=T,col='green')
```

Where the python centroid is:

```
centroid = get_polygon_centroid(np.array([[-6424797.94257892,  7164920.56353916],
                                             [-5582828.69570672,  6739129.64644454],
                                             [-5583459.32266293,  6808624.95123077],
                                             [-5855637.16642608, 7316808.01148585],
                                             [-6424797.94257892, 7164920.56353916]]))
```

And then plotted the centroid of this in red (*-5875318 7010915*) and then the centroid on the same polygon (using python) in green (*-5941009 7067939*) and the simple mean (*-5974304  7038880*) in blue:

[image]

Comment: Did you check if the results of coordinate transformation are the same in both cases? If you just want to debug the centroid computation it would be best to get rid of the coordinate transformation altogether. Also makes it easier for people to run your code :)

Comment: Sorry yes you are right. For the bit below the edit I use projected coordinates, however the result is still the same

Answer (score 1):

It turns out that: if a group of 'Points' are supplied, then instead of guessing a polygon through the points or producing a convex hull - the command automatically gives you the mean of the projected co-ordinates.

However, if you supply a polygon then you get a centroid (the same as the python script) - in my python example I was missing one co-ordinate:

```
centroid = get_polygon_centroid(np.array([[-6424797.94257892,  7164920.56353916],
                                             [-5582828.69570672,  6739129.64644454],
                                             [-5583459.32266293,  6808624.95123077],
                                             [-5855637.16642608, 7316808.01148585],
                                             [-5941009.53089084,  7067939.71641507],
                                             [-6424797.94257892, 7164920.56353916]]))
#polygon closed
#[-5875317.84402261  7010915.37286505]
```

So running this R-script:

```
x = readWKT(paste("POLYGON((-6424797.94257892  7164920.56353916,
                  -5582828.69570672  6739129.64644454,
                  -5583459.32266293  6808624.95123077,
                  -5855637.16642608  7316808.01148585,
                  -5941009.53089084  7067939.71641507,
                  -6424797.94257892  7164920.56353916))"))

python_cent = readWKT(paste("POINT(-5875317.84402261  7010915.37286505)"))
r_cent = gCentroid(x) 

plot(x)
plot(r_cent,add=T,col='red', pch = 0)
plot(python_cent, add=T,col='green', pch = 1)
```

Everything matches nicely:

[image]

I added a bit more info on my [blog](http://iliauk.com/2016/03/02/centroids-and-centres-numpy-r/) if interested.