# r sf package centroid within polygon

Tags: r, r-sf, centroid

I need to add labels to polygons and I normally use the centroid, however the centroid does not fall inside the polygon.  I found this question [Calculate Centroid WITHIN / INSIDE a SpatialPolygon](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44327994/calculate-centroid-within-inside-a-spatialpolygon) but I'm using the sf package.

Below is a toy data

```
rm(list = ls(all = TRUE)) #start with empty workspace

library(sf)
library(tidyverse)
library(ggrepel)

pol <- st_polygon(list(rbind(c(144, 655),c(115, 666)
                         ,c(97, 660),c(86, 640)
                         ,c(83, 610),c(97, 583)
                         ,c(154, 578),c(140, 560)
                         ,c(72, 566),c(59, 600)
                         ,c(65, 634),c(86, 678)
                         ,c(145, 678),c(144, 655)))) %>%
  st_sfc()

a = data.frame(NAME = "A")
st_geometry(a) = pol

a <- a  %>% 
  mutate(lon = map_dbl(geometry, ~st_centroid(.x)[[1]]),
     lat = map_dbl(geometry, ~st_centroid(.x)[[2]]))

ggplot() +
  geom_sf(data = a, fill = "orange") +
  geom_label_repel(data = a, aes(x = lon, y = lat, label = NAME))
```

which results in the following

[image]

Comment: You can replace `~st_centroid` with `~st_point_on_surface`. That is, if you don't care about ever having the true centroid on any polygon.

Comment: This question has more information on the `st_PointOnSurface` from postgis https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/76498/how-is-st-pointonsurface-calculated

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The simple answer is to replace `st_centroid` with `st_point_on_surface`. This won't return the true centroid in cases where the centroid is inside the polygon.

```
a2 <- a  %>% 
  mutate(lon = map_dbl(geometry, ~st_point_on_surface(.x)[[1]]),
         lat = map_dbl(geometry, ~st_point_on_surface(.x)[[2]]))

ggplot() +
  ggplot2::geom_sf(data = a2, fill = "orange") +
  geom_label_repel(data = a2, aes(x = lon, y = lat, label = NAME))
```

**Alternatively**

If the polygon has a centroid that is inside the polygon, use that, otherwise, find a point within the polygon.

```
st_centroid_within_poly <- function (poly) {

  # check if centroid is in polygon
  centroid <- poly %>% st_centroid() 
  in_poly <- st_within(centroid, poly, sparse = F)[[1]] 

  # if it is, return that centroid
  if (in_poly) return(centroid) 

  # if not, calculate a point on the surface and return that
  centroid_in_poly <- st_point_on_surface(poly) 
  return(centroid_in_poly)
}

a3 <- a  %>% 
  mutate(lon = map_dbl(geometry, ~st_centroid_within_poly(.x)[[1]]),
         lat = map_dbl(geometry, ~st_centroid_within_poly(.x)[[2]]))

ggplot() +
  ggplot2::geom_sf(data = a3, fill = "orange") +
  geom_label_repel(data = a3, aes(x = lon, y = lat, label = NAME))
```

The function above `st_centroid_within_polygon` is adapted from the [question you reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44327994/calculate-centroid-within-inside-a-spatialpolygon) for the `sf` package. A more thorough review of how `st_point_on_surface` works can be [found here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/76498/how-is-st-pointonsurface-calculated?newreg=839f6b14ce6b40c9b63956954a3ab969).

Answer (score 2):

Expanding on Mitch's answer because the `st_centroid_within_poly` function provided above only works on single polygons.

To use on multiple polygons, use:

```
st_centroid_within_poly <- function (poly) {

  # check if centroid is in polygon
  ctrd <- st_centroid(poly, of_largest_polygon = TRUE)
  in_poly <- diag(st_within(ctrd, poly, sparse = F))

  # replace geometries that are not within polygon with st_point_on_surface()
  st_geometry(ctrd[!in_poly,]) <- st_geometry(st_point_on_surface(poly[!in_poly,]))

  ctrd
}
```

Comment: It fails at `st_geometry(ctrd[!in_poly,]) <- st_geometry(st_point_on_surface(poly[!in_poly,]))` with `Error in poly[!in_poly, ] : incorrect number of dimensions`