# Improving positioning of map / polygon labels

Tags: r, ggplot2, polygon, r-sf, r-sp

This is an extension to [Improve centering county names ggplot & maps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9441778/improve-centering-county-names-ggplot-maps?noredirect=1&lq=1) and [ggplot centered names on a map](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9441436/ggplot-centered-names-on-a-map?noredirect=1&lq=1). It is not only a theoretical problem, I came across that particular case on answering [How merge specific states together by group with one label in ggplot2 in R?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72708323/how-merge-specific-states-together-by-group-with-one-label-in-ggplot2-in-r/72711104#72711104). Here, I found that there is an L-shaped "grid" which led to a midpoint position outside the polygon. Also, see Henrik's linked thread [Calculate Centroid WITHIN / INSIDE a SpatialPolygon](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44327994/calculate-centroid-within-inside-a-spatialpolygon). .

I wondered if there might be ways to force the label into the polygon, for a "more intuitive" midpoint. "Intuitively" means probably **"the point inside the polygon furthest away from any boundary"** ([an answer to a related thread](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/265475/163696) suggested a function to calculate this, but this function doesn't seem to give a different result than `rgeos::gCentroid` in my example).

Any suggestion should be fully automated, ideally be applicable to any (ir-)regular polygon and also be <strike>independent on the coordinate projection (i.e., the coordinates aspect ratio should not matter)</strike> **correction**: Ideally it **should** depend on the coordinate projection, as this might move the text to an awkward position to the border. Thus, the ideal solution should probably calculate the label position at drawing time.

Very related would be https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/29278/finding-point-in-country-furthest-from-boundary and https://mathoverflow.net/questions/161494/get-a-point-in-polygon-maximize-the-distance-from-borders, but I have no clue how to implement this in R / grid / ggplot2.

```r
suppressMessages({library(ggh4x)
library(sf)
library(dplyr)
library(patchwork)
})

poly_foo <- data.frame(x = c(0:1, rep(2,4), rep(1.5,3), 0), y = c(rep(0,3), 1:3, 3:1, 1))

p <-  ggplot(poly_foo, aes(x, y) ) +
  geom_polygon(color = "black", fill = NA)
p1 <- p +
  stat_midpoint(aes(label = "ggh4x::stat_midpoint\nNot ideal"), geom = "text") 

## Convert to simple feature object for geom_sf
point_sf <- st_as_sf(poly_foo,  coords = c("x", "y"))
poly_sf <- 
  point_sf %>%
  summarise(geometry = st_combine(geometry)) %>%
  st_cast("POLYGON") %>%
  mutate(label = "sf::st_point_on_surface\nNot ideal")

p2 <- ggplot(poly_sf) +
  geom_sf() +
  geom_sf_text(aes(label = label))

## convert to spatial object (sp) for rgeos::gCentroid
xy_lab <- rgeos::gCentroid(as_Spatial(poly_sf))@coords
p3 <- ggplot(poly_sf) +
  geom_sf() +
  annotate(geom = "text", label = "rgeos::gCentroid\nNot ideal", 
           x = xy_lab[1], y = xy_lab[2])
p4 <- p  +
  annotate(geom = "text", x = 1.7, y = .5, label = "more\nintuitive\n\'midpoint\'") 
## it should ideally change with different coordinates
p5 <- p + coord_fixed() + 
  annotate(geom = "text", x = 1, y = .5, label = "more\nintuitive\n\'midpoint\'\ncoordinates changed")

p1 + p2 + p3 + plot_annotation(title = "Example problem")
```

[image]

```r
## Desired output
p4 + p5 + plot_annotation(title = "Desired behaviour")
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-06-26 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: Possibly relevant: [Calculate Centroid WITHIN / INSIDE a SpatialPolygon](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44327994/calculate-centroid-within-inside-a-spatialpolygon); [r sf package centroid within polygon](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52522872/r-sf-package-centroid-within-polygon)

Comment: User @Chris suggested in a comment to a now deleted answer of mine an approach by first calculating the size of the label as a circle and placing that circle somehow into the middle of the polygon. This comes close to the suggestions in those linked maths threads, but again, no idea how to implement this.

Comment: You write "_the point inside the polygon furthest away from any boundary_" - maybe [Pole of inaccessibility](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pole_of_inaccessibility) could be a way forward. Implemented in R [polylabelr::poi](https://search.r-project.org/CRAN/refmans/polylabelr/html/poi.html) "Pole of Inaccessibility (Visual Center) of a Polygon". Based on [`mapbox::polylabel`](https://github.com/mapbox/polylabel). Relevant SO post: [Find visual center of a polygon](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54372892/find-visual-center-of-a-polygon).

Comment: These would always be 'hole-less' polygons?

Comment: @chris good question - I hadn’t thought too much about it before I found those other threads. I guess the ideal solution would also allow for „holy“ polygons.

Answer (score 4):

You can use [`rgeos::polygonsLabel`](https://rgeos.r-forge.r-project.org/reference/labelpt.html) which computes optimal positions for placing labels inside polygons. The default `method` is `"maxdist"` which "*tries to find the label position with a maximal distance from the polygon edges*". Please note that [`rgeos` will retire by the end of 2023](https://r-spatial.org/r/2022/04/12/evolution.html).

```
library(rgeos)
library(sp)
poly_foo <- data.frame(x = c(0:1, rep(2,4), rep(1.5,3), 0), y = c(rep(0,3), 1:3, 3:1, 1))
xy.sp = SpatialPolygons(list(Polygons(list(Polygon(poly_foo)), ID = "test")))
plot(xy.sp)

polygonsLabel(xy.sp, "MY TEST LABEL")
```

[image]

```
plot(xy.sp)
polygonsLabel(xy.sp, "L\na\nb\ne\nl")
```

[image]

```
plot(xy.sp)
polygonsLabel(xy.sp, "MY TEST LABEL\n\n TWO LINES HIGH")
```

[image]

**ggplot2 method**

Store the labels in a vector (or in a column of your spatial data). Calculate the positions of the labels first, and then use these coordinates to plot a `geom_text()`-layer with the labels.

```
library(sf)
library(ggplot2)
# create your vector with labels here...
my.labels <- "This is a test\nlabel"
# I get an error when no plot is present before calculating the 
# label's coordinates.. so plot first, then discard
plot(xy.sp)
# calculate positions for labels
#   For the best results, make sure text height in the ggplot
#   matches the text-height when the positions are calculated !
#   Fiddle with the cex-argument in rgeos::polygonsLabels()
label.pos <- data.frame(
  polygonsLabel(xy.sp, my.labels, doPlot = FALSE),
  labelText = my.labels)
# ggplot polygon + label
ggplot() + 
  geom_sf(data = sf::st_as_sf(xy.sp)) +
  geom_text(data = label.pos, aes(x = X1, y = X2, label = labelText))
```

[image]

Comment: see updated answer for (possible) `ggplot2`-approach

Comment: Oh wow, I didn't know packages could retire from CRAN. This is bad news :( Great solution till then nonetheless :)

Answer (score 2):

Using what you've got along with the information that @Henrik provided, this works pretty well.

There is a catch, though. `ggplot` text to plot sizing is not scaled uniformly. Are you using this in the viewer pane? Are you exporting this? What sizes are you using? For example, the title might be a font size of 15 at 300 dpi, but if you wanted to add text of the same size, you would have to set the size to `15/.pt` (where `.pt` is a static value from the package `ggplot2`).

Additionally, the default font type in `ggplot` is not monospaced—every letter doesn't get the same amount of real estate (like courier, for example).

Check out these plots which have been saved at 300dpi, 3in x 3in, with the text `size = 12/.pt` and `coord_equal`. In the first plot "HHH" takes just over .25 units on the x-axis. In the second, it takes 1.5 units. In the last plot, it takes just over 1/2 unit.

[image]

[image] [image]

This works. However, without a set scaling mechanism, it still requires manual intervention regarding either the font size or the string wrapping.

```
library(polylabelr)
library(stringr)
library(tidyverse)

poly_foo <- data.frame(x = c(0:1, rep(2,4), rep(1.5,3), 0),
                       y = c(rep(0,3), 1:3, 3:1, 1))

p <-  ggplot(poly_foo, aes(x, y) ) +
  geom_polygon(color = "black", fill = NA)
plr <- poi(poly_foo, precision, = .1)
p + 
  coord_equal() +
  annotate("text", x = plr$x, y = plr$y, label = "How about here?" %>% 
             str_wrap(., width = 9/(plr$dist * 2)))

pf2 <- mutate(poly_foo, x = x * 2, y = y^2)
poi2 <- poi(pf2, precision = .1)
ggplot(pf2, aes(x, y) ) +
  geom_polygon(color = "black", fill = NA) + 
  coord_equal() + 
  annotate("text", x = poi2$x, y = poi2$y,
           label = "Intuitive enough?" %>% 
             str_wrap(., width = 9/(poi2$dist * 2)))

pf3 <- mutate(poly_foo, x = x^2, y = y + 4)
poi3 <- poi(pf3, precision = .1)
ggplot(pf3, aes(x, y) ) +
  geom_polygon(color = "black", fill = NA) + 
  coord_equal() + 
  annotate("text", x = poi3$x, y = poi3$y, 
           label = "Intuitive enough?" %>% 
             str_wrap(., width = 9/(poi3$dist * 2)))

pf4 <- mutate(poly_foo, x = x^1/2, y = y^(1/3))
poi4 <- poi(pf4, precision = .1)
ggplot(pf4, aes(x, y) ) +
  geom_polygon(color = "black", fill = NA) + 
  coord_fixed() + 
  annotate("text", x = poi4$x, y = poi4$y,
           label = "Intuitive enough?" %>% 
             str_wrap(., width = 9/(poi4$dist * 2)))
```

[image]
[image]

Comment: Thanks for turning Henrik's suggestion into an answer. This comes close indeed, and would probably be ok in most cases. An ideal solution would figure out the "poi" at drawing time though (by the way, I am missing a library reference in your code), thus being independent of coordinate ratios, or plot/device ratios for that matter. I am aware of the challenges of text sizing, but this is not so much my issue - That the entire label should fit into the polygon is a nice feature but not the point of my question.

Comment: (btw, regarding dimensions of ggplot's geom_text, this thread is also interesting https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55686910/how-can-i-access-dimensions-of-labels-plotted-by-geom-text-in-ggplot2)

Answer (score 1):

Focusing on the calculated nature of the desired result, as applied to possibly 'annoying' label placement in polygons rather than label placement in arbitrary polygons, the following perhaps sketches an approach:

```
library(sf)
library(sfdct)
library(dplyr)
pf1 <- data.frame(x = c(0:1, rep(2,4), rep(1.5,3), 0),
                       y = c(rep(0,3), 1:3, 3:1, 1))

pf1_pt <- st_as_sf(x= pf1, coords=c('x', 'y'))

pf1_poly <- 
pf1_pt %>%
summarise(geometry = st_combine(geometry)) %>%
st_cast('POLYGON') %>%
mutate(label = 'Can be Very Long\nBut Informative!')

pt1_poly_tri <- st_cast(ct_triangulate(pf1_poly))
area_tri_pt1 <- as.numeric(st_area(pt1_poly_tri$geometry))

# get the largest triangles
pt1_poly_lbl_area <- st_union(pt1_poly_tri[area_tri_pt1 >= quantile(area_tri_pt1, 0.75), ])

# get a little more contiguous area, return centroid for ggplot label x,y

plot_lbl_xy <- st_coordinates(st_centroid(st_union(pt1_poly_lbl_area, pt1_poly_tri$geometry[[st_touches(pt1_poly_lbl_area, pt1_poly_tri)[[1]][2]]])))
plot_lbl_xy
  X   Y
1 1 0.5
```

I'll examine this in presence of holes shortly, or before deadline, hopefully.
The difference between polygons without holes and polygons with holes, as triangulated via `sfdct::ct_triangulate`, is that in the first instance, without holes, one can receive a vector of return values of areas, whereas, in the presence of holes, at least for me, a loop is employed to secure individual triangle area values. Absent a loop, all values are summary (ie. total area under `st_area`) that is not desired.

The question, 'what are we dealing with here' can be addressed by `st_is`, where 'geometrycolledtion' will be TRUE in the case of holes present, FALSE otherwise.

The above sketch of approach where there are holes will fail; but, introducing a loop will work. Considering the following system of polygons:

```
outer2 <- matrix(c(0,0,0,32,4,32,4,17,11,17,11,29,15,29,15,17,22,11,22,31,24,31,24,18,29,18,36,12,24,0,0,0),ncol=2, byrow=TRUE)
hole1 <- matrix(c(7,14,7,15,6,15,6,15,7,14), ncol=2, byrow= TRUE)
hole2 <- matrix(c(2,3,7,3,7,5,2,3,2,3), ncol = 2, byrow = TRUE)
hole3 <- matrix(c(19,4, 21,6,17,10,15,8,19.4), ncol=2, byrow=TRUE)
my_painful_poly <- st_polygon(list(outer2,hole1,hole2,hole3))

a_label ='Muchos años después,\n frente al pelotón de fusilamiento,\n el coronel Aureliano Buendía\n había de recordar\n aquella tarde remota\n en que su padre\n lo llevó a conocer\n el hielo'

painful_ct <- ct_triangulate(my_painful_poly)
painful_area <- vector(mode = 'numeric', length=sum(lengths(painful_ct)))
for (m in 1:sum(lengths(painful_ct))) {
    painful_area[m] <- st_area(painful_ct[[m]])
  }
painful_area
 [1] 11.0  7.5  8.0 16.0 36.0 24.0 22.5 36.0 30.0 64.0  2.0 24.0  7.0  1.0  8.0
[16] 26.0 14.0 34.5  9.0 54.0 12.0 26.5 18.5 24.0 17.5 20.0 13.0 45.5 13.0
```

And so, we can proceed as above.

```
painful_lengths <- lengths(painful_ct)
which(seq(min(as.numeric(names(painful_lengths))), max(as.numeric(names(painful_lengths))), 1) %in% as.numeric(names(painful_lengths)) == FALSE)
[1]  5 10 18 20 # our holes as to plot order presumably
```

which seems analogous to @mdsomner 's reflections in [sf-closed #693](https://github.com/r-spatial/sf/issues/693), whom also scripted the above in the context of a different problem [mdsomner - finite element analysis](https://rpubs.com/cyclemumner/306128) as to `quantile`. But generally, the blame is mine.

Comment: Thanks Chris. You've got four days left :D

Comment: I'll likely regret even bringing up 'holes', that are generally not stubborn objects you stub your toe on.